# CardView responding to click events even when hidden

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a form with a clickeable cardview. Depending on some of the options, I hide the CardView setting its visibility to GONE.

Other form controls below the card come up to occupy the space the cardview was taking. However when clicking in the area the Cardview used to be, the onclick event is fired for the cardview.

I even put a check to verify the visibility before the click action, but the cardview repots VISIBLE (even though its not being shown). I use Butterknife for the onClick event:

```
   @OnClick(R.id.logo_cardview)
    public void onLogoClick(){
        if (mLogoCardView.getVisibility() == VISIBLE) {
            Snackbar.make(this, "Logo clicked", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showSettingsDialog();
        }
    }
```

I hide the Cardview using an animation:

```
mAlphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        mAlphaAnimation.setDuration(200);
        mAlphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        mHideListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mMatchInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        };
```

Comment: If the view is NOT visible, how are you generating the onClickEvent?  It doesn't matter if it would respond (if it can't be clicked).

Comment: I click the area the cardview would be, and the event is fired. Why it happens is exactly my question.

Comment: You likely have your onClick registering on a different view then you are thinking then...the current code you have shown is not enough to tell you any more.